# Sending an email to user input email, in a form. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am new to asp.net.  I have an aspx page, that takes in user data (name, number & email) after that information gets submitted to me, **I need to send an email to their input email, with a message of confirmation.**  Can anyone please help me, if this is a broad question can someone please point me in the right direction of where to get a solution to this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all covered in the System.Net.Mail namespace documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

with a code sample on the documentaiton for the MailMessage class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Just be sure you're following the CAN-SPAM act guidelines.  http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

so you can avoid getting blacklisted.  There's also some good general informaiton to be found here: http://systemnetmail.com/